# RabbitMQ messages arriving 3 hours late?

Tags: java, spring, rabbitmq, spring-amqp

I am using RabbitMQ with Spring. After a sender adds a message to the queue, it is not seen by the consumer until 3 hours later. How do I diagnose what the possible problem(s) may be?

Comment: Start with the rabbitmq management console - examine the queue, consumers etc, etc.

Comment: Also it's usually better to share the code/configuration you are using, so other people can help you debug the problem